# SMART: Is my HDD about to get bad sectors and corrupted data?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, smart, bad-sectors, bad-blocks

I am running gsmartcontrol in Linux.

I ran an extended SMART test. The Health Self-Assessment test returned a value of 'PASSED'. However I am concerned about the possibility of any bad sectors and whether there are any personal data saved there unencrypted.

---

**Reallocated Sector Count**

Norm-ed Value: 100

Worst: 100

Threshold: 5

Raw Value: 0

---

**Reallocation Event Count** (*Highlighted in pink*)

Norm-ed Value: 100

Worst: 100

Threshold: 0

Raw Value: 2

---

They both sound like they mean the same thing. What is the difference between them and does the Raw Value of 2 for the latter suggest I will start getting bad sectors?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1218312/pending-sector-issue-does-this-mean-the-hdd-is-failing/1218317#1218317

Answer (score 2):

Raw values are vendor-specific. While I would normally assume the *Reallocated Sector Count* raw value to be the numbers of sectors currently reallocated, and the raw value of *Reallocation Event Count* to be the number of times this happened, so the values 0 and 2 don't make sense, it needn't be this way on all harddrives. E.g., maybe the 2 comes from checking the drive after production.

In any case, since both normalized values are 100, your harddisk is still good and you don't have any reason to worry about bad sectors or failure of your HDD.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install HDD Sentinel for Linux:

[HDD Sentinel](http://www.hdsentinel.com/hard_disk_sentinel_linux.php)

This software with the help of the S.M.A.R.T system makes you a graphic and ETA of the failure (if it's the case)